# Why is my Mixed-Integer Linear Programming problem running slow on python compared to R?

Tags: python, r, linear-programming, solver, mixed-integer-programming

I have a very large mixed-integer linear programming problem that I need to run thousands of times, so speed is a priority.

I need it to run in both `R` and in `python`. My `R` code runs very fast, the solver takes about 0.002 seconds to solve the problem. My `python` code is a different story, it takes anywhere from of 0.05 to 0.80 seconds and often times much more.

I highly doubt that `R` is 25x more efficient than `python`, especially considering that (to my knowledge) both are using `C` code to solve the problem. I'm looking for help to determine how to make my `python` code faster. I assume it starts with getting a different package than the one I have now? I really need the `python` code to consistently be below .01 seconds.

Here is sample `R` code and `python` code that solve the same problem. In this example of my real problem, I'm building "fantasy basketball" lineups with certain constraints. Player pool is 500, must choose exactly 8 players with at least 1 and no more than 3 from each position. Salary must be under 50000. I randomly sample Positions/Salary since the actual solution isn't important as much as the speed.

**R Code**

```
library(lpSolve)
library(dplyr)

# Make dummy dataframe with player positions, salaries, and projected points
Positions <- c('PG', 'SG', 'SF', 'PF', 'C', 'PG/SG', 'SG/SF', 'PF/C')
Position <- sample(Positions, 500, replace = TRUE)
Salary <- sample(seq(3000, 12000, by=100), 500, replace=TRUE)
playerTable <- data.frame(ID = 1:500, Position, Salary) %>% 
  mutate(ProjPts = round(Salary/1000*5))

# Make positional constraint vectors
ConVec_Position <- playerTable %>% 
  select(Position) %>% 
  mutate(AnyPG =  grepl('PG', Position)*1,
         AnySG = grepl('SG', Position)*1,
         AnySF = grepl('SF', Position)*1,
         AnyPF = grepl('PF', Position)*1,
         AnyC = grepl('C', Position)*1,
         
         orPGSGSFPFC = (AnyPG + AnySG + AnySF + AnyPF + AnyC > 0)*1
  ) %>% 
  select(-Position)

# Make salary constraint vectors
ConVec_Salary <- playerTable$Salary

# Get Objective (projected points)
ProjectedPoints <- playerTable$ProjPts

# Make constraint values and directions
ConValGT <- c(1,1,1,1,1, 8) # Must have at least one of each position, and 8 total
ConValLT <- c(3,3,3,3,2, 8, 50000) # Can't have more than 3 of each position, 8 total, and 50000 salary
ConDirGT <- c(rep(">=", ncol(ConVec_Position))) # Make >= directions for each position constraint
ConDirLT <- c(rep("<=", ncol(ConVec_Position) + 1)) # Make <= directions for each position constraint, plus 1 for Salary

# Compile constraint vectors, values, and directions
ConVec_Final <- cbind(ConVec_Position, ConVec_Position, ConVec_Salary)
ConDir_Final <- c(ConDirGT, ConDirLT)
ConVal_Final <- c(ConValGT, ConValLT)

start_time <- proc.time()

sol <- lp("max",
          objective.in = ProjectedPoints,
          const.mat = t(ConVec_Final),
          const.dir = ConDir_Final,
          const.rhs = ConVal_Final,
          binary.vec = 1:length(ProjectedPoints) # All decisions are binary
)

cat("\n--- It took ", round((proc.time() - start_time)[3], 4), " seconds to optimize lineups ---\n", sep = "")
```

**python Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from lp_solve import *
import time

# Make dummy dataframe with player positions, salaries, and projected points
ID = range(500)
Positions = ['PG', 'SG', 'SF', 'PF', 'C', 'PG/SG', 'SG/SF', 'PF/C']
Position = np.random.choice(Positions,500)
Salary = np.random.choice(range(3000,12000,100),500)
playerTable = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID, 'Position': Position, 'Salary': Salary})
playerTable['ProjPts'] = playerTable['Salary']/1000*5

# Make positional constraint vectors
AnyPG = playerTable.Position.str.contains('PG')*1
AnySG = playerTable.Position.str.contains('SG')*1
AnySF = playerTable.Position.str.contains('SF')*1
AnyPF = playerTable.Position.str.contains('PF')*1
AnyC = playerTable.Position.str.contains('C')*1
AnyPos = [1]*500
ConVec_Position = pd.DataFrame({'AnyPG': AnyPG, 'AnySG': AnySG, 'AnySF': AnySF, 'AnyPF': AnyPF, 'AnyC': AnyC, 'AnyPos': AnyPos})

# Make salary constraint vectors
ConVec_Salary = playerTable[['Salary']]

# Get Objective (projected points)
ProjectedPoints = playerTable['ProjPts'].tolist()

# Make constraint values and directions
ConValGT = [1,1,1,1,1, 8] # Must have at least one of each position, and 8 total
ConValLT = [3,3,3,3,2, 8, 50000] # Can't have more than 3 of each position, 8 total, and 50000 salary
ConDirGT = [1] * (len(ConVec_Position.columns)) # Make >= directions for each position constraint
ConDirLT = [-1] * (len(ConVec_Position.columns) + 1) # Make <= directions for each position constraint, plus 1 for Salary

# Compile constraint vectors, values, and directions
ConVec_Final = pd.concat([ConVec_Position, ConVec_Position, ConVec_Salary], axis=1)
ConVal_Final = ConValGT + ConValLT
ConDir_Final = ConDirGT + ConDirLT

# Force all decisions to be binary
vLB = [0] * len(ProjectedPoints) # lower bound 0
vUB = [1] * len(ProjectedPoints) # upper bound 1
xint = [i+1 for i in range(len(ProjectedPoints))] # all decisions are integers (aka all are binary)

solveTimefix = time.time()
[obj, sol, duals] = lp_solve(ProjectedPoints, 
                             ConVec_Final.T.values.tolist(), 
                             ConVal_Final, 
                             ConDir_Final, 
                             vLB, 
                             vUB, 
                             xint)

solveTimeCurrRun = (time.time() - solveTimefix)
print("\n--- It took %s seconds to get all LUs ---\n" % round(solveTimeCurrRun, 2))
```

Any ideas on how to make my `python` code run the same speed as `R`?

Comment: Are you using http://web.mit.edu/lpsolve/doc/Python.htm?

Comment: Why do you need to run this thousands of times? What specifically changes between iterations? Why do you need two languages?

Comment: @Reinderien no, that appears to be `lpsolve55` and I'm using `lp_solve`. Maybe I'll give that a try. And I'm not sure why the other questions are relevant - are you just curious or are you assuming that I don't need what I've said I need? Thanks for your response

Comment: The answers to those questions determine what a proper solution would look like. Otherwise there's big x/y risk here.

Comment: @Reinderien got it, thanks for the explanation. The "projected points" aren't fixed, randomness is introduced each iteration which provides different results and thus different lineups. My R code is where I develop everything for personal use, which I then translate to python for thousands of other people to use. I need other people to have the same speed as my personal solver.

Comment: I see; so this isn't "I need both R and Python"; it's "I need to convert from R to Python". You should only be maintaining one code base.

Comment: @Reinderien I do need separate code for both R and Python. The Python code will not be an exact copy of the R code, there are material differences in building the problem between R and Python. But I still need the Python code to run generally as fast as my R code. Would it be more helpful if I reframed my post as "Help me make my Python MILP run faster"? I don't want to get caught up in R vs Python and all the reasons why I need things the way that I do - I'm just using R as a benchmark.

Comment: Which variables are randomly perturbed? And can you link to `lp_solve`'s documentation?

Comment: It seems odd that you are changing the data wrt the projected points and re-solving yet *not* including the time to reformulate the problem in your timing measurements.  Is that intended?  There may be faster solvers out there (although I'd suspect that differences in solve times when they are this fast is almost all data driven -- meaning some instances will just solve more quickly / are less degenerate) but there may be some overhead in formulating for them.  For example, you're still "paying the `pandas` piper" here and not counting that....  Is that correct?

Comment: @AirSquid great question - yes it's intended, the overhead isn't expensive relative to solving time. Solve time is ~90% of the overall 4min run time. Also, I *know* there are ways I can reduce overhead time, what I don't know is how to reduce solver time. Hence why I'm asking this very specific question - I'm reducing it to the part that I don't know how to improve.

Comment: @Reinderien Thanks - projected points (the coeffecients of objective function) are changed randomly each time. Some players also have maximum and minimum exposure constraints that will force them in/out of lineups during specific iterations, depending on what's happened in previous iterations. Hence why I need to run this 1000 separate times rather than batch-run the top 1000 solutions, the iterations aren't independent. The result of `iteration i` will have a material affect on `iteration i+1`. https://github.com/boris-arzur/lp_solve-python/blob/master/lp_solve.py Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Reinderien I've looked through so many docs finding a solution that will fit with my current workflow that I've forgotten that `lp_solve` actually uses `lpsolve55`. So this uses the same solver as the original doc you sent, just adds an extra function to translate it from matrices, apologies on missing that

Comment: You might have some luck with a persistent solver where you can keep the problem active in the solver and substitute in new parameters  and re-solve which would advantage a warm start, etc.  But I think your expectations are a bit unrealistic.  Some instances will be somewhat parasitic and require much more (unpredictable) b&b effort.  https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/persistent_solvers.html

Comment: I'm not convinced your sample problem is representative of the challenge, and I think you are actually in worse shape for timing. In your mock-ups projected points is a linear function of salary, so any legal combination of players will have same effectiveness at the same aggregate salary. The optimizer will find this almost immediately, with minimal (or no?) branch/bound effort. You might try some significant random noise in projected points and see how that changes things.

Comment: @AirSquid I don't think my expectations are unrealistic, that was the point of showing the `R` code. Both `R` and `Python` use a `C` wrapper for any solver, so theoretically the speed should be relatively close. That's why I'm only testing the time for the *solver* portion - I know the languages will have speed differences elsewhere, but they should be able to have close to the same speed actually solving the problem since they are both just using `C`.

Comment: @AirSquid Believe it or not this example is usually harder for the solver *because* of the linearity. When randomness is introduced, there's usually clear-cut best plays in each iteration that cut down on solve time. I wanted to show as close to the worst-case-scenario for the `Python` solver to really highlight the speed difference (and for the solve-time to be relatively consistent). But again I think this is all besides the point, speed outside the solver isn't an issue. Just want help with which python solver is best for MILP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my craptop this takes about 4 ms, but importantly it is not apples-to-apples. I believe that you are missing a (large) constraint: each individual player can only be assigned to one position.

```py
from time import perf_counter

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
from scipy.optimize import milp, LinearConstraint, Bounds

from numpy.random._generator import default_rng


rand = default_rng(seed=0)

# Make dummy dataframe with player positions, salaries, and projected points
n = 500
position_combos = ('PG', 'SG', 'SF', 'PF', 'C', 'PG/SG', 'SG/SF', 'PF/C')
salary_k = rand.integers(low=3, high=12, size=n)
players = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Positions': rand.choice(position_combos, n),
        'Salary': salary_k * 1_000,
        'ProjPts': salary_k * 5,
    },
    index=pd.RangeIndex(name='ID', stop=n),
)  # 500x3

# Convert from slash-separated position option strings to a dense ID/Position multi-index
exploded_positions = players.Positions.str.split('/', expand=True)  # 500x2
position_values = np.array(('PG', 'SG', 'SF', 'PF', 'C'))
position_sparse = pd.DataFrame(
    (
        exploded_positions.values[:, :, np.newaxis]
        == position_values[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
    ).any(axis=1),
    index=players.index,
    columns=pd.Index(name='Position', data=position_values),
)  # 500x5
position_sparse[~position_sparse] = np.nan
positions = position_sparse.stack().index  # 685x2

# Sparse 2D position assignment matrix with guaranteed single one per column
position_assignments = np.equal.outer(
    positions.get_level_values('Position'),
    position_values,
).astype(float).T  # 5x685

# Sparse 2D player assignment matrix with guaranteed single one per column
player_assignments = np.equal.outer(
    positions.get_level_values('ID'),
    players.index,
).astype(float).T  # 500x685

# Dense salary assignment (row) with repeats according to player ID
salary_assignments = players.Salary[positions.get_level_values('ID')]  # 685

# Cost values: negative projected points, only where a player can take a given position;
# multi-indexed by ID and Position
c = -players.ProjPts[positions.get_level_values('ID')].astype(float)
c.index = positions  # 685

integrality = np.ones(shape=c.size, dtype=np.uint8)  # 685
bounds = Bounds(
    lb=np.zeros_like(c),
    ub=np.ones_like(c),  # 685
)

A = scipy.sparse.csc_array(
    scipy.sparse.vstack((
        scipy.sparse.csr_array(np.ones_like(c)),       # The total number of selected players must be fixed
        scipy.sparse.csr_array(salary_assignments),    # There is a maximum salary
        scipy.sparse.csr_array(position_assignments),  # Each position count has a min and max
        scipy.sparse.csr_array(player_assignments),    # One player cannot occupy multiple positions
    ), format='csc')  # this is what milp uses; see _milp_iv()
)  # 507x685
lb, ub = np.block([
    [8, -np.inf, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, np.full(shape=n, fill_value=-np.inf)],
    [8,  50_000, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, np.ones(n)],
])

t0 = perf_counter()
result = milp(
    c=c, integrality=integrality, bounds=bounds,
    constraints=(LinearConstraint(A=A, lb=lb, ub=ub),),
)
t1 = perf_counter()
assert result.success, result.message

print(result.message)
print(f'Solution in {1e3*(t1-t0):.1f} ms')

outputs = pd.Series(name='Assigned', data=result.x, index=positions)
selections = outputs[outputs > 0.5].index
merged_outputs = players.loc[selections.get_level_values('ID')].set_index(selections)
print(merged_outputs, end='\n\n')

print('Total:')
print(merged_outputs[['Salary', 'ProjPts']].sum().to_string())
```

This uses HiGHS in the backend; I have not attempted `lpsolve55`. The output is

```
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
Solution in 3.4 ms
             Positions  Salary  ProjPts
ID  Position                           
314 SF              SF   10000       50
390 PG              PG    3000       15
447 SG              SG    3000       15
467 SF              SF   10000       50
480 PF              PF    7000       35
484 SG              SG    3000       15
487 C                C    7000       35
494 C                C    7000       35

Total:
Salary     50000
ProjPts      250
```

You could also try running on PuLP/CBC (I have not shown that here).

Comment: I like this...  did you see my comment above regarding the linearity between salary->projected points?  I think that relationship is giving false hopes here....

Comment: Fine? All I have is your test data. If you're worried about a realistic distribution of salary, estimate its distribution in real life and then modify your test data to suit. Otherwise there's nothing to be done.

Comment: @Reinderien Thanks for posting! Really appreciate you walking me through it and being patient with me. I need to upgrade to Python3.10 before running this so it'll take me some time to sort that out, but just want to say this is exactly what I was looking for. And the comment above was not from me, I explain why linearity isn't false-hope to the user in the comments above.

Comment: @Reinderien Got python3.11 running and it's consistently running around .004sec, 50x faster than my current solver. Thank you for sticking with me, this is a huge help! Now I just need to find a consistent generalized way to turn constraints in matrix-format to be read by SciPy's milp.