# Python Pulp - 0/1 Knapsack Problem - How to Ensure Items (IDs) are Selected At Most Once

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am a little out of my element here: I am a statistician who mainly works in SAS and R. I am attempting to code what is essentially the classic knapsack problem in Python using Pulp. My data look something like this (this is a simplified version):

The fan.csv example data

```
id       Fan    Cost    Switch
10001   32.83   3.18    A/B
10003   75.25   4.20    C
10005   71.60   8.79    A/B
10010   24.23   9.99    C/D
10011   98.69   8.88    D
10012   48.81   8.68    C/D
```

I need to maximize Fan while choosing 1 or 2 items in each Switch category (e.g. 1 "A", 2 "Ds", etc.) all while coming in under a Cost threshold. So far, pretty standard.

My issue is that some items can be in one or the other Switch category (see obs with '/' in the Switch value - e.g., id 10001 can serve as either 'A' or 'B'). Because I am a statistician, I think in terms of n x k datasets and in this case I would set the data up in long form (as if these were repeated measures data):

```
id       Fan    Cost    Switch
10001   32.83   3.18    A
10001   32.83   3.18    B
10003   75.25   4.20    C
10005   71.60   8.79    A
10005   71.60   8.79    B
10010   24.23   9.99    C
10010   24.23   9.99    D
10011   98.69   8.88    D
10012   48.81   8.68    C
10012   48.81   8.68    D
```

HOWEVER, I have essentially taken someone else's example code to call the Pulp optimization model and I adapted it to my situation. **My current problem is that it is unclear to me how to add constraints to the linear optimization model so that each item (each id) is selected at most just once.** This is an issue because of the way I 'unpacked' the Switch variable and listed multiple id's with different Switch values.

My code appear below. In step 1, I convert the fan.csv data into long form (I wrote this code myself). Step 2 is mostly the example data that I adapted. The sample code organizes the data in nested dictionaries and then calls the Pulp functions to specify the optimization model.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pulp import *
import numpy as np

# Step 1

os.chdir("E:\\")

df01 = pd.read_csv("fan.csv")

df02 = df01[df01['Switch'].str.contains('/')]
df03 = df01[~df01['Switch'].str.contains('/')]

df02[['Swit1','Swit2']] = df02.Switch.str.split("/", expand=True)
df04 = pd.wide_to_long(df02, ["Swit"], i="id", j="Pos")
df04.reset_index(inplace=True)
df04.drop(["Pos"], axis=1, inplace=True)

df05 = pd.concat([df04,df03])
df06 = df05.sort_values(by=['id'])
df06.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df06.loc[(~df06['Switch'].str.contains('/')), 'Swit'] = df06.Switch

# Step 2    

df07 = df06.groupby(["Swit", "id", "Fan", "Cost"]).agg('count')
df07 = df07.reset_index()

costs = {}
fans = {}

for sth in df07.Swit.unique():
    df07_sth = df07[df07.Swit == sth]
    cost = list(df07_sth[['id', 'Cost']].set_index("id").to_dict().values())[0]
    fan = list(df07_sth[['id', 'Fan']].set_index("id").to_dict().values())[0]
    costs[sth] = cost
    fans[sth] = fan


sth_num_available = {
    "A": 1,
    "B": 1,
    "C": 1,
    "D": 2,
                    }

cost_cap = 25

_vars = {k: LpVariable.dict(k, v, cat='Binary') for k, v in fans.items()}

model1 = LpProblem("Fans", LpMaximize)
fanval = []
costval = []
switch_constraints = []

for k, v in _vars.items():
    costval += lpSum([costs[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    fanval += lpSum([fans[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    model1 += lpSum([_vars[k][i] for i in v]) == sth_num_available[k]

model1 += lpSum(fanval)
model1 += lpSum(costval) <= cost_cap
model1

model1.solve()
```

- To be clear, the fan.csv data I listed above has so few rows of data that Pulp finds that the problem is infeasible. These data are just the example data for this post. In reality, I have ~1,000 rows of data and the data change and are updated every day.

## EDIT 1

I have 2 additional constraints to add. I am including this in this post b/c this issue this related to the initial post.

The expanded fan.csv example data are:

```
id       Fan    Cost    Switch  Hit Group   Cat
10001   32.83   3.18    A/B       0   G1    C1
10003   75.25   4.20    C         1   G1    C2
10005   71.60   8.79    A/B       0   G1    C3
10010   24.23   9.99    C/D       1   G2    C1
10011   98.69   8.88    D         1   G2    C2
10012   48.81   8.68    C/D       1   G2    C3
```

## New Constraint 1

The knapsack solution can include a maximum of *n* ids coded 1 for Hit from any one Group.

I tried adapting Reinderien's code for this constraint. Here *n* is set to 2:

```
df02 = df01.copy()
df02.set_index(["id","Group",], drop=False, inplace=True)
for G, total in df02.Assign.groupby(level='Group').sum().items():
    model1.addConstraint(name='Group' + G + 'Hit', constraint=df02.Hit.dot(total) <= 2)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3015, in dot
    if lvals.shape[0] != rvals.shape[0]:
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>>
```

## New Constraint 2

Additionally, the knapsack solution must consist of at least 2 of the categories (Cat).

Here is my adapted code:

```
df04 = df02.copy()
df04.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df04.set_index(["id","Cat",], drop=False, inplace=True)
for category, total in df04.Assign.groupby(level='Cat').sum().items():
    model1.addConstraint(name='Cat_' + category, constraint=total >= 2)
```

This runs without error and BUT DOES NOT represent the intended constraint.

============================================

Comment: I recently wrote an example of what is very nearly this [exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76732293/313768). Tomorrow I can demonstrate how to adapt it to your data.

Comment: When you say one or the other switch category, I assume that you mean mutual exclusion.

Comment: @Reinderien Yes, Switch is mutual exclusive and collectively exhaustive.

Comment: @Reinderien - I just read through your solution to the post you linked to. Yes, this seems like the same issue. I would very much appreciate it if you can demonstrate how to adapt it to my data using Pulp. I will check back tomorrow. Many thanks!

Comment: You need to stop naming your dataframes by numeric index...

Comment: I think you are getting "lost in `pandas` sauce" here.  I think breaking things out of `pandas` and into more easily labeled sets/dictionaries is going to lead to a much more legible and trouble-shootable expression of the problem.

Comment: Do some more testing and you'll find that your formulation for New Constraint 2 is incorrect. You can't just sum over category groups, because you don't care about the assignment sum: you care about the sum of an auxiliary variable indicating whether there is _at least one_ assignment in each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [other answer I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76732293/313768) uses scipy. Here I demonstrate PuLP because it's what you were using. Aside:

> [I mainly work] in SAS and R

R has linear program support of its own, so why switch to Python? Anyway, the main gist of the demonstration below is that multi-indexing makes things easy:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pulp

df = (
    pd.read_fwf('fan.csv')
    .set_index('id')
    .rename(columns={'Switch': 'SwitchOptions'})
)

# arbitrary columns, id index, values are switch string fragments
exploded_switch = df.SwitchOptions.str.split('/', expand=True)

# A, B, C, D
switch_values = pd.unique(exploded_switch.stack())

# ABCD columns, id index, values are True or NaN to indicate switch match
switch_sparse = pd.DataFrame(
    (
        exploded_switch.values[:, :, np.newaxis]
        == switch_values[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
    ).any(axis=1),
    index=df.index,
    columns=pd.Index(name='Switch', data=switch_values),
)
switch_sparse[~switch_sparse] = np.nan

# Multi-index to 10 ID/switch values
df = switch_sparse.stack().align(df)[1]

# Reasonable assignment variable names; will be unique
var_names = (
    'asn_i'
    + df.index.get_level_values('id').astype(str)
    + '_s'
    + df.index.get_level_values('Switch')
).to_series(index=df.index)

# Assignment variables, named, binary, with same ID/switch multi-index
df['Assign'] = var_names.apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpBinary)

# Indexed total switch availability series
switch_avail = pd.Series(
    index=switch_sparse.columns,
    data=(1, 1, 1, 2),
)

# Maximize total Fan via dot product
model = pulp.LpProblem(name='Fans', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
model.objective = df.Assign.dot(df.Fan)
model.addConstraint(name='cost_cap', constraint=df.Assign.dot(df.Cost) <= 25)

# Constrain assignments by switch availability
for switch, total in df.Assign.groupby(level='Switch').sum().items():
    model.addConstraint(name='switch_' + switch, constraint=total <= switch_avail[switch])

# Constrain IDs to be assigned exclusively. Only add constraints where more than one switch is possible.
id_groups = df.Assign.groupby(level='id')
for ID, total in id_groups.sum()[id_groups.count() > 1].items():
    model.addConstraint(name=f'excl_id_{ID}', constraint=total <= 1)

# include a maximum of n ids coded 1 for Hit from any one Group
for group_name, total in df[df.Hit == 1].groupby('Group').Assign.sum().items():
    model.addConstraint(name=f'hit_group_{group_name}', constraint=total <= 2)

cat_names = pd.Series(name='Cat', data=df.Cat.unique())
cat_used = cat_names.apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
cat_used.index = pd.Index(name='Cat', data=cat_names)

# the knapsack solution must consist of at least 2 of the categories
model.addConstraint(name='cats_used', constraint=cat_used.sum() >= 2)

# if the ID is assigned, its category must be assigned
for (ID, switch), row in df.iterrows():
    model.addConstraint(name=f'cat_i{ID}_s{switch}', constraint=row.Assign <= cat_used[row.Cat])

# if none of the IDs in the category are assigned, the category must not be assigned
for cat, total in df.groupby('Cat').Assign.sum().items():
    model.addConstraint(name=f'cat_{cat}', constraint=cat_used[cat] <= total)

print(model)
model.solve()
assert model.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

df['Assign'] = df.Assign.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value)
print(df)
```

```
Fans:
MAXIMIZE
32.83*asn_i10001_sA + 32.83*asn_i10001_sB + 75.25*asn_i10003_sC + 71.6*asn_i10005_sA + 71.6*asn_i10005_sB + 24.23*asn_i10010_sC + 24.23*asn_i10010_sD + 98.69*asn_i10011_sD + 48.81*asn_i10012_sC + 48.81*asn_i10012_sD + 0.0
SUBJECT TO
cost_cap: 3.18 asn_i10001_sA + 3.18 asn_i10001_sB + 4.2 asn_i10003_sC
 + 8.79 asn_i10005_sA + 8.79 asn_i10005_sB + 9.99 asn_i10010_sC
 + 9.99 asn_i10010_sD + 8.88 asn_i10011_sD + 8.68 asn_i10012_sC
 + 8.68 asn_i10012_sD <= 25

switch_A: asn_i10001_sA + asn_i10005_sA <= 1

switch_B: asn_i10001_sB + asn_i10005_sB <= 1

switch_C: asn_i10003_sC + asn_i10010_sC + asn_i10012_sC <= 1

switch_D: asn_i10010_sD + asn_i10011_sD + asn_i10012_sD <= 2

excl_id_10001: asn_i10001_sA + asn_i10001_sB <= 1

excl_id_10005: asn_i10005_sA + asn_i10005_sB <= 1

excl_id_10010: asn_i10010_sC + asn_i10010_sD <= 1

excl_id_10012: asn_i10012_sC + asn_i10012_sD <= 1

hit_group_G1: asn_i10003_sC <= 2

hit_group_G2: asn_i10010_sC + asn_i10010_sD + asn_i10011_sD + asn_i10012_sC
 + asn_i10012_sD <= 2

cats_used: C1 + C2 + C3 >= 2

cat_i10001_sA: - C1 + asn_i10001_sA <= 0

cat_i10001_sB: - C1 + asn_i10001_sB <= 0

cat_i10003_sC: - C2 + asn_i10003_sC <= 0

cat_i10005_sA: - C3 + asn_i10005_sA <= 0

cat_i10005_sB: - C3 + asn_i10005_sB <= 0

cat_i10010_sC: - C1 + asn_i10010_sC <= 0

cat_i10010_sD: - C1 + asn_i10010_sD <= 0

cat_i10011_sD: - C2 + asn_i10011_sD <= 0

cat_i10012_sC: - C3 + asn_i10012_sC <= 0

cat_i10012_sD: - C3 + asn_i10012_sD <= 0

cat_C1: C1 - asn_i10001_sA - asn_i10001_sB - asn_i10010_sC - asn_i10010_sD
 <= 0

cat_C2: C2 - asn_i10003_sC - asn_i10011_sD <= 0

cat_C3: C3 - asn_i10005_sA - asn_i10005_sB - asn_i10012_sC - asn_i10012_sD
 <= 0

VARIABLES
0 <= C1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= C2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= C3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_i10001_sA <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_i10001_sB <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_i10003_sC <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_i10005_sA <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_i10005_sB <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_i10010_sC <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_i10010_sD <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_i10011_sD <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_i10012_sC <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_i10012_sD <= 1 Integer

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 30 COLUMNS
At line 137 RHS
At line 163 BOUNDS
At line 177 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 25 rows, 13 columns and 70 elements
...

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                255.58000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.00
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

                Fan  Cost SwitchOptions  Hit Group Cat  Assign
id    Switch                                                  
10001 A       32.83  3.18           A/B    0    G1  C1     0.0
      B       32.83  3.18           A/B    0    G1  C1     1.0
10003 C       75.25  4.20             C    1    G1  C2     1.0
10005 A       71.60  8.79           A/B    0    G1  C3     0.0
      B       71.60  8.79           A/B    0    G1  C3     0.0
10010 C       24.23  9.99           C/D    1    G2  C1     0.0
      D       24.23  9.99           C/D    1    G2  C1     0.0
10011 D       98.69  8.88             D    1    G2  C2     1.0
10012 C       48.81  8.68           C/D    1    G2  C3     0.0
      D       48.81  8.68           C/D    1    G2  C3     1.0
```

Comment: This is perfect. I just went thru your code once, so I am still digesting it (and may have some follow-up questions, but I think I follow what you are doing). Many, many thanks!!

Comment: I have two more constraints that I need to add to this optimization model. I am having a hard time coding these in Python. Any chance you could provide some guidance? If so, I will edit the original post with details. Thanks!

Comment: Go for it, though if they're over complex it might suit a new question better

Comment: Thanks. I included the follow-up question in this post b/c it seemed related to me. Please see Edit 1. Once again, thanks for looking at this.

Comment: @Dan see edit - hit coding (so far as I understand it) is trivial, but category counts require more work. You need assignment variables added for each category, and supporting constraints.

Comment: Once again, many thanks! I am running, dissecting, and digesting your new code now.